# Sending an email from the browser with javascript and flash... is it possible?

Tags: javascript, flash, email, browser

I'm wondering if its possible to do what I'm thinking, and if it is possible, does anyone know of a flash object that does what I need?

I know a Flash object can provide a javascript API to interact with it, what I dont know is can Flash send an email directly without the need to talk to the webserver to do so? If thats possible would it not be possible to write a flash object that did nothing but provide an API to send emails? Has such a thing been created that is out there for others to use?

I'm looking to create a email form on a web page but the site is static (no server scripting). In my situation server scripting is not possible as there is no server, the site is 100% client side on a CD/DVD/USB Stick.

Comment: I have done this with a jQuery plugin for [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com) but it's not so safe because it exposes the API key for the plugin. That's the only way I could think of, but only for non-production machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using flash, although I have not done so myself and I wouldn't advise it. The general strategy would be to connect to a specific mailserver using sockets.

1. The server would need a "Socket Policy File" available on port 843. See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html for more. It would give permissions for connecting to the chosen port for the mail relay (e.g. 25).
2. You can then use the flash Socket library in order to, in effect, create a telnet client. See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf7.html
3. Construct your email as a payload for the socket, and send it. See http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html

Of course, if you are distributing these CDs to the entire world, your mail server socket policy would have to accept connections from anyone on any machine, you'd be running an open mail relay, chaos would ensue, dogs and cats living together...

Now it's unlikely that you'll find a public SMTP server that lets you do this, and if you really don't have access to anything server-side whatsoever (no webserver, no control over any SMTP server) then you'll need to rely on the client-side mailto: links instead.

Answer (score 3):

No, flash nor JS can do this alone as they are client-side technologies. You need to create a server side script to send the email and then request it from your client.

It doesn't matter if the swf file is on a USB stick or wherever, you can still connect to a server. Most web hosts support php so that would probably be the easiest way. Check out [this Google search](http://www.google.ee/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Vba&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=send+email+flash+php&oq=send+email+flash+php&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=59530l60041l0l60121l4l3l0l1l1l0l161l320l0.2l2l0).

**EDIT:** if you can't use a server then you could use a mailto link, this opens the users default email client.

```
var mailto:String = "mailto:email@example.com";
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(mailto), "_blank");
```

You can also add a subject and body. See http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html for the syntax.

Comment: I have no server, again this is all local files on a CD that gets handed to a person to browse. I don't know flash at all, last time I used it was years ago, but I was hoping it could send an email without the need for a webserver :)

Comment: If you don't have a server than your task is impossible. You can try to prompt user to their default email client maybe. Also, simple web servers are very cheap, some even free.

Answer (score 0):

Since it runs off of a CD in the user's computer and you have no server, your best (only?) option would be to run the user's own mail client.

Try creating a [mailto link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) dynamically with JavaScript and then clicking it. It should run the local mail client (Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.) with the input you specify. The users would have to click "send" themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send an email if there's no internet connection, doesn't matter if you use JavaScript, Flash or anything else.

Edit: http://code.google.com/p/smtpmailer/
This is written in ActionScript and might fit your needs.

http://flashflex.com/sending-mail-in-actionscript-using-smtp/
This is some background information.

Comment: The user would need an internet connection, yes, but the html documents would be on CD so there is no option to run PHP/ASP on a server. All I got in html/javascript/flash. I was hoping flash could do the tcp/ip and send the email to a smtp server (perhaps a generic gmail account) and provide a javascript api.

Comment: @Justin808 "but the html documents would be on CD so there is no option to run PHP/ASP on a server". This sentence makes no sense. You can always have a backend as long as you have an internet connection.

Comment: @RobFox - I guess, but maintaining that backend indefinitely over the years is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm writing an application that runs in a browser for x-platform compatibility, I'd rather not have to write windows/mac/linux applications that the intended audience wouldn't take the time to install. I'm looking for an easy (for the user) way to get formated feedback to me without the need to run a backend somewhere. I have email, they have email, this should be possible. I looked into mailto: but you're limited on the size of the email because of the URL size limit.